# C++ Macro assembly error

Tags: c++, assembly, macros, x86, inline-assembly

I'm trying to create a macro for `__declspec(naked)` functions, but I keep getting the following errors:

```
'sub' identifier is reserved word
'mov' identifier is reserved word
inline assembler syntax error in 'first operand'; found'register'
```

Here is my macro:

```
#define NAKED_START __asm{push ebp\
                      mov ebp, esp\
                      sub esp, __LOCAL_SIZE\
                     }
```

Do I really have to use this:

```
#define NAKED_START __asm{push ebp}\
                    __asm{mov ebp, esp}\
                    __asm{sub esp, __LOCAL_SIZE}
```

Comment: The \ at end of line gets converted to a space and the newline disappears. I suspect the assembler doesn't like being given three instructions on one line. Is ";" legal to separate the instructions?

Comment: No, ';' is not working either.

Answer (score 1):

Try getting rid of the braces and putting `__asm` before each instruction. That way the compiler can tell where each instruction starts.